# Aligning basic ggplots with faceted ggplots in ggarrange (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, alignment, facet-wrap, ggpubr

I have created numerous ggplots graphs that I would like to organize with the ggarrange function of the ggpubr package.
I run into an issue when I try to combine basic ggplots with faceted ggplots: I cannot align them anymore.

Here is a reproducible example of my issue:

```
#Creating some data
df2 <- data.frame(supp=rep(c("VC", "OJ"), each=3),
       dose=rep(c("0.5", "1", "2"),2),
       len=c(6.8, 15, 33, 4.2, 10, 29.5))
head(df2)


#normal ggplot #1
p1<-ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=dose, y=len, group=supp)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()

#normal ggplot #2 with a different y axis
p2<- ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=dose, y=10*len, group=supp)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()

#faceted plot
p3<-p2+
  facet_wrap(. ~ supp)
```

When I combine two basic ggplots and force vertical alignment with the y axis, it works like a charm!

```
ggarrange(p1,p2,
          nrow=2,
          align="v")
```

[image: two basic plots]

But when I combine a basic plot with a faceted plot, the alignment does not work.

```
ggarrange(p1,p3,
          nrow=2,
          align="v")
```

[image]

I get the following warning:

> Warning message: Graphs cannot be vertically aligned unless the axis
> parameter is set. Placing graphs unaligned.

Would you please help me solve this problem? I have seen other potential ideas to solve this issue with cowplot, but I would really like to stick to ggpubr!

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you considered the patchwork package for plot composition?

Comment: No,  I did not! But I just checked it out and it worked like a charm! Would you like to propose an answer with the patchwork package that I can accept?

Comment: Sure though I feel a bit bad about giving an answer with merely two lines of code :')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using the patchwork package. Assume we have setup the plots `p1` and `p3` as described in the original post. Then, with some patchwork magic, we combine the plots. The `/` operator indicates that p1 should be above p3.

```r
library(patchwork)
p1 / p3
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could pad the y axis to adjust it in the ggarrange. You can pad the margin around the y axis which will allow the two figures to line up (a bit hacky though).

```
df2 <- data.frame(supp=rep(c("VC", "OJ"), each=3),
                  dose=rep(c("0.5", "1", "2"),2),
                  len=c(6.8, 15, 33, 4.2, 10, 29.5))


#normal ggplot #1
p1<-ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=dose, y=len, group=supp)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 5)))

#normal ggplot #2 with a different y axis
p2<- ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=dose, y=10*len, group=supp)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()

p3<-p2+
  facet_wrap(. ~ supp)

ggarrange(p1,p3,
          nrow=2)
```

Comment: I see, thanks for the help! With the amount of graphs I have, it's going to be a little too hacky though!